# Is this really “Napoleon’s March”?

Tags: napoleonic-wars, napoleon, music, identification

The Chabad/Lubavitch Jewish group have a tradition that this song originated as a military march played by Napoleon’s armies as they invaded Russia:

http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/862529/jewish/26-Napoleons-March.htm

Is there any historical backing to this tradition?

Comment: I can't answer, but having listened to it (never heard it before your post), I find myself wondering: do they re-use the tune for something else, and if so what? It doesn't seem to have a melody long enough, or catchy enough, to become a folk/work/kid's song... is there a paramilitary Chabad group that drills to this march? ;)  (My neighbors are Lubavitchers; maybe I'll ask them...) It seems like a weird bit of music to end up on the Chabad website; can you shed any light on the backstory?

Comment: @MT_Head From [heichalhanegina.blogspot.com](http://heichalhanegina.blogspot.com/2007/01/rav-baal-hatanya-and-napoleons-march.html): “When the Alter Rebbe heard the marching song of Napoleon's army, he said it was a march of victory. He then decided that the song should be used in one’s service to Hashem. [On Yom Kippur, before the _shofar_ is blown (at the end of _Tefillas Neila_), it is customary in Lubavitch to sing Napoleon’s March.]” (Note: “The Alter Rebbe” refers to [Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shneur_Zalman_of_Liadi) (1745–1812)).

Comment: Huh. Thanks! I'll listen for that next Yom Kippur. Not sure I'll recognize it, though. Our neighbors do a lot of singing... but can they carry a tune? Not so much. ;)

Comment: Also, given how Napoleon's invasion turned out, why would they take the Alter Rebbe's choice of music seriously?  A march of victory, forsooth!

Comment: @MT_Head The Alter Rebbe was fiercely opposed to Napoleon and prayed for his downfall, as elaborated on in the above article. His appropriation of the tune would have been part of his campaign to defeat Napoleon by "redeeming" the spiritual energies he possessed, in the mystical tradition of _ithapcha_.